# UWP Community Toolkit DataGrid control : how to align cell content to right

Tags: datagrid, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have a numeric column in a [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) I want its content be right-aligned. I have [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/), mostly [Customizable templates and styling for cells, rows and headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/styling_formatting_options#4-customizable-templates-and-styling-for-cells-rows-and-headers) where I ended up with this code to accomplish right-align cell content:

```
<controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

As is to be expected, this code really does what I want, but with all the cells. I want only the numeric column to have this property, and only it, but I have been unable to accomplish this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want only the numeric column to have this property, and only it

For your requirement, you could give cell style to specific `DataGridTextColumn` property  like the follow.

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn  >
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

The style will work for specific column.

Comment: So I need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and set `DataGridColumns` to the binded column I need to be right-aligned?

Comment: Yep, you need set specific cell style for DataGridColumns.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` instead of `HorizontalAlignment` because the horizontal alignment changes the cell size. The default Cell `HorizontalAlignment` is `Stretch` whis is stretched the cell size to column size.

Here is a picture when you set the  `HorizontalAlignment`
[image: cell size is changes]

And Here is the picture when you set the `HorizontalContentAlignment`
[image]

---

Basically You can define three different cell style:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellLeft" TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellCenter" TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellRight" TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
```

Use it like `CellStyle` when you define a column.